# printer Api's in Linux

Tags: linux, windows

I am new to Linux Environment and familiar with Printer API's in windows. so what are the    equivalent API's of `Start Doc`, `Openprinter`, `EnumPrinters` in Linux??.

Answer (score 0):

[CUPS](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-cups.html) is the standards-based, open source printing system developed by Apple Inc. for Mac OS® X and other UNIX operating systems like Linux. But it doesn't contain any document-descripting API. It can handle existing format of docs like PostScript, PDF and JPEG. So you can use whatever you like to create files in such formats, and then send it to CUPS by `lpr` or [CUPS api](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-cups.html).

You may find [LP and CUPS Overview](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6729) useful.